# Facing AccessDeniedException while my user has the required permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'm trying to execute some batch import on a DynamoDb table from CLI. When I execute the command, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: User: arn:aws:iam::********:user/Mehran is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:BatchWriteItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:********:table/History with an explicit deny
```

This is while I have explicitly added the `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` permission to my user. And when I go to `Access Advisor` tab for my user, I can see the mentioned permission granted.

Could someone please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the user policy has `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess`, the effective policy for the user also has an explicit deny on resource `arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:********:table/History`. One solution is to remove the explict deny policy for the user but there is a reason the explicit policy is there. An `explicit deny` overrides an `allow`.

See: [Determining Whether a Request is Allowed or Denied](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow)

[image]